# Stop a function returning an array of objects from firestore from running continuously running SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, function, swiftui

The function is returning the arrays from a snapshot and using them as the output of the function. I am calling the function is a separate view which maps out the arrays. However, the function does not stop running after I open that view.

```
    func fetchReplies(post: Post) -> [Post] {
        let query = COLLECTION_POSTS.document(post.id).collection("post-replies")
            .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)

        query.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in

            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.post = documents.map({ Post(dictionary: $0.data()) })
        }
        print(DateInterval())
        return self.post
    }
```

I am calling the function in the view like this.

```
ScrollView() {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(repliesViewModel.fetchReplies(post: self.post)) { post in
                        PostCell(post: post)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
```

The replies are populating the view but its calling the function repeatedly even after leaving view. I have the Date object there so that I can see it firing.

Comment: Store the result of the function call in a property and use that property in yourForEach

Comment: I tried doing that, but I need the function to take an argument from the view (the .id, which is a string). I can’t create the function in the view file because it complains on so many different lines. Any pointers for calling the stored property with the argument from the view?

Comment: The function doesn’t need to be in the view file and you can call it from `.onAppear` for instance

Comment: The problem I’m having is calling it with the id. How can I pass the id into the observed variable I create in my view model

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with your code.

Your `fetchReplies()` function calls the async `getDocuments(completion:)` function. `getDocuments(completion:)` won't finish until after your `fetchReplies()` has returned, so you can't have `fetchReplies()` return a result. You need to make `fetchReplies()` take a completion handler. Something like this:

```
func fetchReplies(post: Post, completion: (Post) -> Void){
    let query = COLLECTION_POSTS.document(post.id).collection("post-replies")
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)

    query.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in

        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        completion(documents.map({ Post(dictionary: $0.data()) })
        )
    }
    print(DateInterval())
}
```

You call `fetchReplies()` in a ForEach, which must return a View synchronously. You can't do that. For one thing, it will call fetchReplies repeatedly. For another, `fetchReplies()` is (or should be) an async function, so it can't return it's results synchronously like it needs to in order to create a View.

I guess you will need to build your Views empty, and then install your data into them once `fetchReplies()` function's completion handler fires. (I'm not very experienced with SwiftUI.)

Comment: Ok I somewhat understand, I am pretty new to firestore. If I got rid of the return and output, how would I be able to make the observable object ‘post’ (that I make in the view model) take an additional argument after it is passed into the view?